# Testing with React Apollo ignores variables

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-apollo, react-testing-library

I have fairly simple test setup very similar to what's coming with [tutorial repo](https://github.com/apollographql/fullstack-tutorial/) from Apollo GraphQL and described in [their documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/testing/).

Here's the query:

```
const GET_USER_WITH_SPEND_CONTROL = gql`
    query GetUserWithSpendControl($userToken: ID!) {
        me(token: $userToken) {
            firstName
            lastName
            spendControl {
                amountAvailable
                currencyCode
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Here's the test:

```
const mockUserSpendControl = {
  me: {
    firstName: "Andrii",
    lastName: "Gorishnii",
    spendControl: {
      amountAvailable: 1000,
      currencyCode: "USD",
    }
  }
};

describe('Account Summary', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  it('renders account summary', async () => {
    const mocks = [
      {
        request: { query: GET_USER_WITH_SPEND_CONTROL },
        result: {
          data: mockUserSpendControl
        },
      },
    ];
    const { getByText } = await renderApollo(<AccountSummary/>, {
      mocks,
      cache,
      addTypename: false
    });
    await waitForElement(() => getByText(/Gorishnii/i));
  });
});
```

The wrong thing about this test is that it works while it shouldn't: GQL schema declares required variable `userToken` however if I add it to the test like this:

```
...
request: { query: GET_USER_WITH_SPEND_CONTROL, variables: {userToken: "56aed"} },
...
```

It actually fails the test.

Does anyone have similar problems with testing React Apollo components?

P.S. I'm having bigger problem where my original query goes like this:

```
const GET_USER_WITH_SPEND_CONTROL = gql`
    query GetUserWithSpendControl($userToken: ID!) {
        currentUserToken @client @export(as: "userToken")
        me(token: $userToken) {
            firstName
            lastName
            spendControl {
                amountAvailable
                currencyCode
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

And I can never match the mocked result with the query which is using variables exported from client's cache. But this will probably be next question after I solve "simpler" problem.